# Curved vector bundles and central extensions of $\pi_1$

Tags: vector-bundles, curvature

Every flat vector bundle on a manifold comes from a representation of $\pi_1$, by the equivalence between flat vector bundles and local systems.

However, I've seen it mentioned that **non-flat** vector bundles on a manifold correspond to representations of a **central extension** $\widehat{\pi}_1$ of $\pi_1$. Is this correct, and what does the action of the central element correspond to geometrically?

---

*Example:* In the Atiyah-Bott Yang Mills paper, they mention that a rank $n$ vector bundle with curvature $\kappa$ on a Riemann surface $X$ corresponds to a representation $\rho$ of $\widehat{\pi}_1(X)$ with 
$$\prod [\rho(a_i),\rho(b_i)]\ = \ \exp(2\pi i \kappa/n)$$
where $a_i,b_i$ are the standard generators of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29099/central-yang-mills-connections-and-flat-connections-with-prescribed-holonomy